# I do not know the IP addresses used for PageSpeed Insights

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I have two inquiries regarding applying PageSpeed Insights to our company's test site.

1. I would like to know the exact IP addresses from which PageSpeed Insights accesses our site.
   This is because our test site has restrictions on the allowed IP addresses for access. Therefore, in order to use PageSpeed Insights, we need to grant additional permissions for communication based on IP addresses. I would like to know the specific IP addresses for this purpose.
2. I would like to know if there is a possibility for our test site to be indexed by Google. Since it is a test site, we want to avoid it being indexed and appearing in the Google search results.

I have been able to make some educated guesses about the IP addresses based on the access log data when PageSpeed Insights was used. I noticed that the User_agent contained the term "chrome-lighthouse". However, I would like to know the IP addresses accurately.

Answer (score 0):

1. The IP address of all Google Services is provided in this link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322?hl=en. You can add all of them to the allowed IP address list.
2. To prevent your website from being indexed by Google or other search engines, I suggest using a robots.txt file.